# Programmatically adding new entry in Strapi

Tags: strapi

I have my Strapi deployed, and users are able to log in to their account and add new entries to the server. The server will then store the content in PostGres on Google Cloud Service. However, I want to be able to reflect the newly added entries for my **local server** as well, since I need to manually add some image assets for each entry. Is there a way for me to somehow retrieve the new entries from database and directly add it to my local Strapi admin dashboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use same database for local dev and production versions. In that way the content of production version is the same as dev version.

Comment: Yes that makes sense! However, even though the database content is still the same, the content in the Strapi dashboard will be synced. I would like the content for the dashboard to be updated with what i have in the production as well.

Comment: I’m sorry I don’t understand what you mean? If the database is the same for dev and production, everything what is in the database are same for both. Only those fields (= content types) you add or remove in dev version will not be available in production version until you push a new version to production server. After deploy the both versions will be exactly the same.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry maybe I am misunderstanding something fundamental here. When I open up my dashboard, whether it is in production or in development, the strapi population will populate all the content for each content type directly from the database? Is that correct? I thought that the strapi application populates all the content from the build file rather than from the database somehow.

Comment: The data (for ex. restaurant name) is in the database. The database structure is defined in json files in some folders and build makes those file structures ready for deploy (I don’t know are they minified and maybe some other ways compressed/tree shaken). This is a clever system because now you can use what ever database with your local dev system and the production database’s structure will be updated accordingly when deployed. More info in documentation: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/models.html#concept

Comment: okay thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I tried to connect to the same postgres server in google cloud from my local server and the connection doesn't seem to work. From the Strapi documentation it seems like Strapi doesn't support connection to the Google Cloud SQL server..